# Кэширование данных создаваемого объекта

Tags: c#, кэширование

При создании объекта, инициализируются 4 списка типа `List<double>`, в которые заносятся данные из БД. В моем проекте объект создается раз 1000. Такая логика. Так вот, как лучше реализовать кэширование данных списков. Чтобы при создании объекта, если уже были созданы списки с данным условием, то мы просто берем их из кэша?
Ключи для хранения в кэшэ - Название таблицы, и 2 даты - начальная и конечная, между которыми берем данные.

Comment: Статический словарь заведите и кешируйте в него. Метод создающий эти данные перепишите, чтобы он сначала искал в словаре и возвращал оттуда, иначе создавал заново, сохранял в словарь и возвращал

Comment: @Андрей Спасибо большое, буду реализовывать

Comment: если в программе есть несколько потоков - возьмите именно ConcurrentDictionary. Обычный Dictionary при многопоточной работе ведет себя несколько непредсказуемо.

Comment: @PashaPash как раз-таки да, у меня будет несколько потоков одновременно создавать объект и брать из кэша по ключу списки. Почитаю про это, спасибо

Comment: Я кода то [делал что то подобное](https://github.com/tym32167/arma3beclient/blob/master/src/Arma3BE.Client.Libs/Repositories/PlayerRepository.cs#L44). Код, конечно, не идеальный, но как пример что можно сделать пойдет + работает и в многопоточном сценарии.

Comment: Обратите внимание на [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), он потокобезопасный.